# Gazebo Harmonic: How to access a gz::sensors::CameraSensor object/shared_pointer inside a SystemPlugin?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gz-sim

I have a SystemPlugin that I attached to the sdf of a camera as [here](https://github.com/sparsh-b/gz-sim-plugins/blob/c29547c9a89a8b249d0e505df9763246c4022ff4/ws/src/ariac_camera_plugin/models/rgb_camera/model.sdf#L22). This seemed to work & I could see the gz transport topic publishing the camera image feed.

Now, I want to enable/disable the sensor (camera here) from inside the Plugin. I understand I can do that using the [SetActive](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/8/classgz_1_1sensors_1_1Sensor.html#a3172f15c4f5860e8c276b394f75bae1d) method of `gz::sensors::CameraSensor` class. However, I couldn't find any examples of how to access an object of or a `shared_ptr` to `gz::sensors::CameraSensor` from inside the [`Configure`](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1ISystemConfigure.html#ac5fc9ce04c3166a5322016b5f2d303e0) function of the plugin (I thought the references of `gz::sim::EntityComponentManager` or `gz::sim::Entity` passed as arguments to `Configure` function of the plugin should be able to give me access to the `gz::sensors::CameraSensor` object but wasn't able to figure it out).

```
class CustomPlugin : public gz::sim::System,
                     public gz::sim::ISystemConfigure 
{
    void Configure (const gz::sim::Entity &_entity,
                      const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> &_sdf,
                      gz::sim::EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
                      gz::sim::EventManager &_event_mgr) 
    {

        // How to access gz::sim::CameraSensor object here?

    }
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!